# Looping through the ADO fields collection in VBA with an empty recordset

Tags: excel, vba, ado, recordset

I have an ADO recordset that returns no rows (which is expected), but my watches panel shows a valid field collection, with column names that I want to store / capture.

However, using code like

```
x = rs.Fields(idx)
```

returns the error '3021' : Either BOF or EOF is True.  Requested operation requires a current record.

My question is is it possible to read the Fields collection (noting that the contents that I can see in the watches panel appear correct and what I want to be able to grab), and if not, what are the "gotchas" that explain why?

Many thanks
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need name:

```
x = rs.Fields(idx).Name
```

`Field(idx)` is the value, which does not exists.

Comment: Thanks @Remou - this caused some confusion!

Comment: Wow, this indeed caused confusion here too. I thought I couldn't even get a Field, much less its name, if I was in an EOF state which led to bad things in my ADO Recordset wrapper class. Default properties, they're evil!